# Excel file contain 5 sheets how can i read all the data at a time using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using this ...code but it will read index wise

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("PILOT.xlsx"));
              XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
              XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
              Iterator < Row > rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
              while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
              {
                 row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                 Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                 while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                 {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                           if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                        }
                    //   System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t " );
                       break;
                       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                       System.out.print(
                       cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t\t " );
                       break;
                    }
                 }
                 System.out.println();
              }
              fis.close();
           }
```

give any shortest way for read all the data at a time.....i am using maven POI dependency .....help me

Comment: while executing this code  Numeric data will print like decimal type .....and Date format also print like decimal points....cloud you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the workbook has 5 sheets, but you are only reading one sheet in your code. Therefore in order to read the data from all the sheets in the workbook, you need to wrap your code in a loop. So where you currently have:

```
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

replace that with the loop below, and put the remaining code inside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        // Your remaining code here
    }
```

That will enable you to extract the data from all 5 sheets.